# Spring: which Spring Boot version for Spring HATEOAS 0.19.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I want to use the latest stable version `0.19.0.RELEASE` of `Spring HATEOAS`. I combine it with the latest stable version `1.2.6.RELEASE` of `Spring Boot`. In the `build.gradle` we find among others

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
...
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.6.RELEASE")
    compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.19.0.RELEASE'
}
```

When I start the main application, I get the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.
HypermediaAutoConfiguration$HypermediaConfiguration$HalObjectMapperConfiguration': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalHandlerInstantiator.<init>
(Lorg/springframework/hateoas/RelProvider;Lorg/springframework/hateoas/hal/CurieProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    ...
    at ... Application.main(Application.java:...)
```

That looks terrible, but we can translate it. On the one hand, in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration` of `spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar` we find

```
public class HypermediaAutoConfiguration {
    ...
    protected static class HypermediaConfiguration {
        ...
        protected static class HalObjectMapperConfiguration {
            ...
            private void registerHalModule(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
                ...
                Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator instantiator = new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(
                        HalObjectMapperConfiguration.this.relProvider,
                        HalObjectMapperConfiguration.this.curieProvider);
                ...
```

That means the two argument Constructor of `Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator` is called. On the other hand, in `Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator` of `spring-hateoas-0.19.0.RELEASE.jar` the constructors unfortunately have only 3 or 4 arguments:

```
public class Jackson2HalModule extends SimpleModule {
    ...
    public static class HalHandlerInstantiator extends HandlerInstantiator {

        ...
        public HalHandlerInstantiator(RelProvider resolver, CurieProvider curieProvider,
                MessageSourceAccessor messageSource) {
            ...
        }

        public HalHandlerInstantiator(RelProvider resolver, CurieProvider curieProvider,
                MessageSourceAccessor messageSource, boolean enforceEmbeddedCollections) {
            ...
        }
        //no further constructors
```

I have tried newer, not stable `Spring Boot` versions, but this does not work, either. I don't want to use a lower version of `Spring HATEOAS`, because in this case other errors occur.

Do you know if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `1.2.5.RELEASE` with `0.19.0.RELEASE` without any errors. Upgraded a few dependencies like this :

```
<properties>
        <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
        <spring-hateoas.version>0.19.0.RELEASE</spring-hateoas.version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it. When I use `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.5.RELEASE")` in my `build.gradle`, I still find `spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar` in my Gradle Dependencies.

Comment: Use `gradle dependencies` and find out what references that version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint with the jackson version! Now the old error with `Spring HATEOAS` version `0.18.0.RELEASE` does not occur anymore.

Comment: i tried this, but still have objectMapper exceptions :-/  for me only works spring-boot:1.2.5.RELEASE with hateoas 0.18... 0.19 wont work... :/

Comment: spring boot 1.3 was released a few days ago, if you can, upgrade and you will have 0.19 out of the box

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have multiple versions of `spring-hateoas` jars, Here is dependency configuration i have.

```
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:1.2.6.RELEASE"){
exclude module: 'spring-hateoas'
} 
compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.19.0.RELEASE'
```

And as per Maven central `spring-boot-starter-hateoas:1.2.6.RELEASE` compile dependency, should work with updated `spring-hateoas 0.19.0`